# not able to update android studio 3.1: Conflicting configuration : 'armeabi-v7a,x86' during sync project

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

this is my build gradle (app) file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

def versions = ['appcompat_v7' : '25.1.0',
                'butterknife'  : '8.4.0',
                'leak_canary'  : '1.5',
                'card_view'    : '25.1.0',
                'design'       : '25.1.0',
                'photoview'    : '1.2.4',
                'play_services': '10.0.1']



task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) {
    configFile file("${project.rootDir}/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml")
    configProperties.checkstyleSuppressionsPath = file("${project.rootDir}/config/quality/checkstyle/suppressions.xml").absolutePath
    // Where is my suppressions file for checkstyle is...
    source 'src'
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/gen/**'
    classpath = files()
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    flavorDimensions "versionCode"

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    dexOptions {
        // Skip pre-dexing when running on Travis CI or when disabled via -Dpre-dex=false.
        preDexLibraries = preDexEnabled && !travisBuild
    }

    defaultConfig {

        ndk {
            abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
        }

        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            //runProguard true
            proguardFile file('android.pro')
            proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk true
        }
    }

    // map for the version code


    productFlavors {

        playstore {

        }
        develop {
        }
    }


    lintOptions {
        //I'm too lazy to translate everything
        abortOnError false
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
        }
    }
}

def Properties props = new Properties()
def propFile = new File('signing.properties')
if (propFile.canRead()) {
    props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

    if (props != null && props.containsKey('STORE_FILE') && props.containsKey('STORE_PASSWORD') &&
            props.containsKey('KEY_ALIAS') && props.containsKey('KEY_PASSWORD')) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(props['STORE_FILE'])
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = props['STORE_PASSWORD']
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = props['KEY_ALIAS']
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = props['KEY_PASSWORD']
    } else {
        println 'signing.properties found but some entries are missing'
        android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
    }
} else {
    println 'signing.properties not found'
    android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
}


dependencies {
    compile project(":tess-two:tess-two")
    compile project(":volley")
    compile project(":real-time-ocr")

    compile 'com.github.barteksc:pdfium-android:1.5.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'src/main/libs', include: '*.jar')

    debugCompile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:${versions.leak_canary}"
    releaseCompile "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:${versions.leak_canary}"
    compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    compile "com.commit451:PhotoView:${versions.photoview}"
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.2'
    compile "com.google.guava:guava:18.0"
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
    compile "com.android.support:design:${versions.design}"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${versions.appcompat_v7}"
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.5'
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${versions.card_view}"
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${versions.butterknife}"
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:9.4.0+'
    compile group: 'com.facebook.android', name: 'facebook-android-sdk', version: '4.25.0'



    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito:1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.google.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.0'
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.17'
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-all:1.10.19"
    testCompile("org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc2") {
        exclude group: 'commons-logging', module: 'commons-logging'
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2+') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1+@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }


    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.shawnlin:number-picker:2.4.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'



}
crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
    androidNdkOut '/Users/renard/devel/textfairy/tess-two/tess-two/obj'
    androidNdkLibsOut '/Users/renard/devel/textfairy/tess-two/tess-two/libs'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

android studio can't sync project and get me this error:

> Conflicting configuration : 'armeabi-v7a,x86' in ndk abiFilters cannot be present when splits abi filters are set : x86,armeabi-v7a
>
> Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018
>
> Configuration 'debugCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'debugImplementation'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018
>
> Configuration 'androidTestApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'androidTestImplementation'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018
>
> Configuration 'releaseCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'releaseImplementation'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018
>
> Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018
>
> Configuration 'testApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018
>
> Configuration 'androidTestCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'androidTestImplementation'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018
>
> The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
>   Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018.
>
> Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018
>
> The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
>   Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018.
>
> Configuration 'testCompile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018
>
> Configuration 'testApi' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'testImplementation'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018
>
> The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore.
>   Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018.
>
> Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018

if I delete this line

```
defaultConfig {

    ndk {
        abiFilters 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
    }
```

the project sync sucessfully
but when build give me this error

> Failed to execute aapt

I already try to clean and rebuild project but still not working!
I also post the build.gradle (Project) file

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    }
}



allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
        }
        maven { url 'https://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/' }
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }

}

ext {
    travisBuild = System.getenv("TRAVIS") == "true"
    // allows for -Dpre-dex=false to be set
    preDexEnabled = "true".equals(System.getProperty("pre-dex", "true"))
}
```

my gradle-wrapper.properties file

```
    #Tue Mar 27 14:42:14 CEST 2018
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

and my gradle.properties file

```
    ndkDir=/Users/giuliopettenuzzo/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxPermSize\=512m
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`ndk.abiFilters` configuration means that only selected processor architectures of native libraries will be included in the final APK.

On the other hand, `splits.abi`.`enable true` tells the compiler to generate separated APKs for selected architectures.

It seams that this two configuration can't be set together. So you have two options:

1. Disable splitting APK (you've figured it out already). Than you will have one APK.
2. Remove `ndk.abiFilters` setting. Than you will have multiple (probably much smaller) APKs. Moreover, with `universalApk true`, an universal APK with all architectures will be generated (probably much larger than in option 1).

Than, replace `compile` with new keyword `implementation`. I think, this is clear from error message.

Comment: > Moreover, with universalApk true, an universal APK with all architectures will be generated (probably much larger than in option 1).
This is insanely stupid. If I want abi split, I get invalid universal apk if, for instance, my dependencies provide more abis they I do.

Answer (score 7):

Finally I got it working by putting

```
abi {
    enable false
    reset()
    include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a'
    universalApk true
}
```

and `multiDexEnabled true` but I don't know if this sorted out the problem or just ignoring the error.

Comment: Where should i put this ?  in Default config?

Comment: @HarshBhavsar You should put this in android/app/build.gradle

Comment: @PratikSinghal Where? I put in that file and i have error "Coiuld not find method abi() for arguments[build_randomchars_run_closure3@randomnumbers] on root project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Comment: @DiCri There are two build.gradle files. Are you sure, you are trying to put it in right file ? You need to put it in android/app/build.gradle and not android/build.gradle.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add **"x86"** here:

```
ndk {
    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86"
}
```

inside the defaultConfig.

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1' //referencia  a la version de firebase
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1' // referencia a la base de datos
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.6.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'

// aqui se agrega la referencia a la autentificacion
}
```

**replace compile by implemenntation
androidCompileTest by androidTestImplementation **

Comment: I don't know why this answer get downvoted, but this works for me, and somehow reasonable according to what Android Studio informed after my previous gradle build.

Answer (score 0):

I opened an old project and when I wanted to build it, I was getting a lot of error which was very frustrating. I replaced compile with implementation and added all the required codes. At last the project built successfully.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0-rc2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```