# Build failed with an exception - (Build file build.gradle line: 27)

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

I want to get output from the app for the App Store but I get this error:

```
    For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety
    
    
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    
    * Where:
    Build file 'C:\Users\Mahan\FlutterProjects\dooneh\android\build.gradle' line: 27
    
    * What went wrong:
    A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
    > A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
       > Conflicting configuration : 'armeabi-v7a,x86_64,arm64-v8a,x86' in ndk abiFilters cannot be present when splits abi filters are set : x86_64,armeabi-v7a,arm64-v8a
    
    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
    
    * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
    
    BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

in line 27 on `build.gradle` from `android`:

```
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
```

i add to file `build.gradle` from `android/app` this line:

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```

I tried many ways and even used the one mentioned for [build without null safety](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65663541/10860442) and [this](https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety) on `pub.dev`

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49802507/10860442) solved my problem. Interestingly, I did not use splits in my `build.gradle`, but removing this line of code solved the problem:

```
ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
```